# PHP page not working on Bluemix, but works fine on my local webserver

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to run this code

```
include 'safe/DAL.php';
$feedback = getAllCups();
if ($feedback != "Error.") {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($feedback); $x++) {
    $tmp_cup = $feedback[$x];
    echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item">';
    echo '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">';
    echo $tmp_cup->getCupName() . ', ' . $tmp_cup->getYear();
    echo '</h4>';
    echo '<p class="list-group-item-text">Vinnare: Inte avslutad ännu</p>';
    echo'</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<a href="#" class="list-group-item">';
    echo'<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Inga cuper hittades</h4>';
    echo'</a>';
}
```

on my bluemix app (which works fine on my local webserver, when I'm debugging)

It shows nothing, and stops any other code from being shown after this code.

I've tried to enable error reporting like this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but this also, does not show anything.

Why does it work on my local webserver, but not on bluemix?

Comment: Check your server's error logs.

Comment: Are you sure the right file is on the server? Have you tried restarting the server? Do you have some kind of opcode cache?

Comment: I have seriously no clue about how to debug it on my server. @SecondRikudo

Answer (score 2):

Likely, the answer to your problem lies in some error being generated by Bluemix or your code. In a production system, you don't want to output stack traces and other system errors to potential clients, so Bluemix generally forces errors to be logged only to log files.

From your command line, log in to Bluemix using the `cf` tool, then run this command to get the most recent logs from your app: `cf logs <app_name> --recent`.

The result should show you which file and line is causing the app crash (which may in fact be something within DAL.php).

Comment: I've only just begun using bluemix. Where can I get hold of the cf tool and how do I use it? And how come it chrashes on bluemix, but not on other web servers?

Comment: You can obtain the CF CLI tool here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#downloads.

It's a command-line tool, so after you install it, you use it from the Command Prompt or Terminal on your computer. First, run `cf login`, which will ask you for the CF API to contact. In the case of Bluemix, this is https://api.ng.bluemix.net. Next, enter your email and password. After successful login, you can run the command to get your logs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: As to why your app works locally but not on Bluemix, it could be related to any number of things. Likely, it's some environmental thing you're not taking into account. If you're connecting to a database, you need to have that bound and then use the VCAP_SERVICES environment information to access it. Additionally, filesystem access is limited in Bluemix, so you usually can't write to disk directly. The logs will hopefully tell you what the exact issue is.

Comment: Has this been helpful? Any success?

Comment: Sorry Matt I've been busy. I will however need to address this issue sooner or later and then I'll try this approach first of all and let you know.

Comment: I've included the logs from the CLI tool, feel free to have a look. I can not find any critical errors. Sorry again for the late response.

Comment: Did you visit the page that renders as blank today before pulling the logs?

Comment: Yes,I wrote cf logs myApp, then I navigated to  where the problem arises.

Comment: Are you connecting to a database? MySQL perhaps? Can you show the code in `DAL.php`? I've occasionally seen DB related code that fails without throwing errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting to a MySQL database in DAL.php. it seems like that's the problem, but I don't know how to solve it since the connection is working everywhere else except on Bluemix, and as you say it throws no errors.

Comment: Please show the basic code from `DAL.php`. You could also troubleshoot it by inserting `echo` statements at various places in your code and when they stop showing up, you've found the issue.

Comment: Sorry Matt, but I've decided to abandon bluemix and use a different webserver due to lack of time to solve this issue. I'm grateful for your persistence in this matter tho, so thanks for trying.